# Overwriting in a txt file using C++

Tags: c++

So basically I have this content in a txt file:

`506; 25; ,thing1 thing2, thing3; 10, 15`
`600; 12345678910; whatever1, whatever2, whatever3; 15, 60`

I want to change the `12345678910` to a shorter string like, for example, 2.
So I run the code and it does change the string between the first two `;...;` in line 2.

After running the txt is like this:

`506; 25; ,thing1 thing2, thing3; 10, 15`
`600; 2; whatever1, whatever2, whatever3; 15, 60`
`; 15, 60`

However if I change to a larger string, it doesn't create a third line.

```
while (j < storage_line.size())
{

    size_t found = storage_line[j].find(string_to_add);
    if (found != std::string::npos)
        {
            size_t found2 = storage_line[j].find(";"); //finds the position of the first ;
            size_t found3 = storage_line[j].find(";", found2 + 1); //finds position of the second ;
            storage_line[j].replace(found2 + 2, found3 - found2 - 2, string_to_add);
            file2 << storage_line[j] << endl;
            cout << storage_line[j] << endl;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            file2 << storage_line[j] << endl;
            cout << storage_line[j] << endl;
            j++;
        }
}
```

First I read the uploaded the content on each line of the file to a vector of strings, `storage_line`.

If I do `cout << storage_line[j] << endl;` it shows just changing the string I want to change and doesn't create a third line.

With the `file2 << storage_line[j] << endl;` it creates an extra line as shown above.

Comment: You just inserted the string in the middle of the line, making it longer.  You didn't write any newline characters. Why would you expect a new line?

Comment: @KennyOstrom what? i used storage:line[j].replace(position i want to insert the new string, number of characters to be removed in the original string starting at the position I want to insert new string, string I want to add)

Comment: @KennyOstrom with cout works perfectly fine, but not when I write to the file

Comment: No ... the line can be as long as you want. It ends at an "end of line" character (or characters). Try writing std::endl to the file where you want the line to end. Right now, you're just writing a longer string, then the same endl it already had, so the number of lines won't change.  Just because a long string gets wrapped into a second line on the screen doesn't mean anything -- it's just an effect of displaying it in the console.

Comment: @KennyOstrom i already figured it out. I had to 
file.open("info_textfile.txt" ,ios::in)
extract the info into a vector of strings
close.file()
file.open("info_textfile.txt" ,ios::trunc | ios::out)
and then write what I want. I had to clean the file before writing on it.